# How to test if a mounted share is still functional

Tags: linux, bash, samba

I have a set of linux machines with samba ( and other ) shared drives. There are automated scripts that mount these shares. My problem is, sometimes a host machine will go offline, but I can't find a good way to test for this from the client.

I was checking the `mount` command output for this purpose, but mounts that have since gone offline still appear in that output. My next attempt has been to try to perform an `ls /media/mount`. This will either return the files from the share or fail with a `"ls: cannot access /media/mount: Host is down"` error message. This would be fine except that `ls` is very slow, or sometimes just hangs.  I've also tried `df`, this does give me the info I need, without having to parse errors, but it's still slow and Im concerned it also could hang.

Is there a way to test share connectivity without the slowness / hang problem? Ideally in a way were the issued command doesn't have to error out to get at the answer of whether reading and writing to a share can actually happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for instance:

**touch /root/test > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?**

0

**touch /blablablaroot/test > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?**

1

Better if you add timeout to the command:

**timeout 15 touch /blablablaroot/test > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?**

1

I hope it helps.

Comment: initial tests were failing... due to permissions!  Seems to work, thanks!